# SQL Server doesn't use Index if it contains NOT NULL clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, query-optimization

I have the following query.

```sql
declare @p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000)
SELECT 
            [UserId] AS [UserId]
            FROM [dbo].[Users]
            WHERE ([TenantId] = @p__linq__0)
                AND ([IpId] = @p__linq__1)
                AND ([IpUserId] = @p__linq__2)
```

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1Ma-oXI2)

Itexecutes correctly using an existing index. The execution plan shows correctly, that the expected number of returned rows is ~1.

Now consider the following query, which has an additional but redundant `IS NOT NULL` clause.

```sql
declare @p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000)
SELECT 
            [UserId] AS [UserId]
            FROM [dbo].[Users]
            WHERE ([TenantId] = @p__linq__0)
                AND ([IpId] = @p__linq__1)
                AND ([IpUserId] = @p__linq__2)
                AND ([IpUserId] IS NOT NULL)
```

[Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry3JbjmI3)

Now suddenly the optimizer estimates the number of returned rows to be 5000. While the execution plan is still correct in this basic example, this causes issues in more complex cases (see below). Obviously the additional restriction shouldn't change anything, as the expression `([IpUserId] = @p__linq__2)` already filters for IpUserIds being not null. What could be the reason for that issue?

The table structure is as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [IpId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IpUserId] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [Identifier] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [TenantId] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] [datetime] NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.[Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [UserId] ASC
    )
)
go

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_IpId_IpUserId] ON [dbo].[Users]
(
    [TenantId],
    [IpId],
    [IpUserId]
)
WHERE ([IpUserId] IS NOT NULL)
go

CREATE INDEX [IX_IpId_IpUserId_Nullable] ON [dbo].[Users]
(
    [TenantId] ASC,
    [IpId] ASC,
    [IpUserId] ASC
)
go
```

Interestingly, if I drop index `IX_IpId_IpUserId`, everything works as expected. It seems that the problem is somehow related to the `NOT NULL` clause, which is part of the index' specification but which I can't easily get rid of.

Here are the query plans of a slightly more complex example where the problem leads to a full clustered index scan.

- *Without* NOT NULL (correct plan): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1TkSo7U2
- *With* NOT NULL clause (wrong plan): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyxqNoX8h

Thanks for any help.

The DBMS used is Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8.

Comment: The `[IpUserId] IS NOT NULL` is pointless anyway as `[IpUserId] = @p__linq__2` *cannot* be true if `[IpUserId]` has the value `NULL`. `WHERE SomeCol = @Variable` and `WHERE SomeCol = @Variable AND SomeCol IS NOT NULL` are effectively synonyms, so there no need for `IS NOT NULL` clause.

Comment: *Side note, there is no need for that overuse of parathesis and delimit identifying. Your `WHERE` can just be `TenantId = @p__linq__0 AND IpId = @p__linq__1`, etc. Generally, you use parenthesis when dealing with `OR` clauses.*

Comment: Please share the execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: How many records to you have in the users table? My experience is looking at execution plans is only relevant if you a) have issues with performance now (be logical and don't do preventative optimization) - b) have representative number of rows (i.e., don't analyze with 10 rows, you just get silly numbers.

Comment: Try changing your code (I assume you are using Linq2SQL) to use `.Where(p => IpId == yourvalue.Substring(0, 399)` I think the optimizer is not realizing that the `nvarchar(4000)` value can match the `nvarchar(400)` in the index

Comment: @ThomA The SQL has been generated by EntityFramework, so I cannot easily modify it. But as the additional `IS NOT NULL` clause should be redundant, it shouldn't have any effect, but apearently it does.

Comment: @Tobbi The table has > 1M entries and the query is executed often. We indeed have some performance issue here.

Comment: @Charlieface We are using Entity Framework 6.4. Thank you, will try your suggestions.

Comment: @Charlieface I added execution plans to my question and also did some clarification. Reconsidering the execution plans, it seems that I simplified the problem a little too much. The problem seems to be that the statistics are calculated incorrectly.
So while the calculated plan is still correct in this very basic example, the incorrect statistics cause issues in more complex queries. See above.

Comment: Both of these plans are not making use of the `IX_IpId_IpUserId` filtered index, tehy are both inefficient for different reasons. You should try getting that to work properly. The `OR` is going to mess  things up whatever you do, do you really need it? if you do, improve the `IX_Identifier` index by adding `TenantId` as a key column. Are you sure your EF model has the correct size for the column? Consider transitioning to EF Core.

Comment: @Charlieface They don't make use of the index, but if I drop the index IX_IpId_IpUserId, then the plan is correct. If I recreate it, it's wrong again. It seems that the NOT NULL clause being present in both, the index and the query, causes the optimizer to prefer it over IX_IpId_IpUserId_Nullable, but as the statistics are estimated incorrectly, it then doesn't use it. Is this a bug? I agree that the OR isn't ideal. I could work around it by running two distint queries for the branches of the OR instead. Working with a UNION instead did not solve the problem.

Comment: For now I solved the problem by getting rid of the NOT NULL clause in the query, which is redundant. I did this by implementing a custom IDbCommandTreeInterceptor (weird stuff). However, as there's still something wrong with the indexes, the problem could appear in all kinds of places any time again, so the solution is not too robust. Will also take another look at the variable size you suggested. Thank you for now!

Comment: I think what's happening is it's trying to use the filtered index, then deciding the `nvarchar(4000)` doesn't match. Although come to think of it, filtered index statistics don't update automatically, so try `UPDATE STATISTICS [IX_IpId_IpUserId] ON  dbo.Users WITH FULLSCAN`

Comment: Played around with the column sizes, didn't change anything. Also looked at the statistics. Couldn't update them yet, but they are quite up to date. More importantly, the statistics of both indexes, `IX_IpId_IpUserId` and `IX_IpId_IpUserid_Nullable`, are almost identical. No signs that the difference between both could cause so significantly different estimations.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the parameter `@p__linq__2 nvarchar(4000)`, which does not match the `IpUserId nvarchar(400)` column. I think the compiler is struggling to match it when the extra `IS NOT NULL` is there, because it tries to match it too early before any downcasts are tried.

Linq2SQL (which it seems you are using) will automatically force a `nvarchar(4000)` value for parameters in most cases, and it's pretty much impossible to get it to change that. Either transition to a better ORM like Entity Framework (where you can specify the column's `MaxLength`), or try the following code:

```cs
.Where(u => u.IpUserId == yourvalue.Substring(0, 399))
```

Do *not* substring it outside of the lambda or it won't work.

---

One final option is to create a Table Valued Function which does the conversion

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetUsers (@IpUserId nvarchar(400))
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
SELECT u.*
FROM dbo.Users u
WHERE u.IpUserId = @IpUserId;
```

Then you can use this function in [the normal way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/tvfs).

Comment: Thanks for this interesting insight. Unfortunately the 'Substring' trick does not work. Based on your feedback I also tried to change the declared type to nvarchar(400) at least when executing the query manually, but also no luck.